# Configuration System Failed To Initialize

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, configuration-files

In my application when I try to get the connection string by using this code :

```
 System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ConnectionString;
```

It throws an exception that "Configuration System Failed To Initialize". Where is the format of app.config wrong ?

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>


      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConStr" connectionString="Integrated Security=false;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=funny;password=veryfunny;Initial Catalog=vegimanager;Data Source=.\sqlexpress;"/>
      </connectionStrings>



      <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <section name="Vegi_Manager.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false"/>
        </sectionGroup>
      </configSections>




      <userSettings>
        <Vegi_Manager.Properties.Settings>
          <setting name="FIRMNAME" serializeAs="String">
            <value/>
          </setting>
          <setting name="FIRMADDRESS" serializeAs="String">
            <value/>
          </setting>
          <setting name="FIRMCITY" serializeAs="String">
            <value/>
          </setting>
          <setting name="FIRMSTATE" serializeAs="String">
            <value/>
          </setting>
          <setting name="FIRMPHONE" serializeAs="String">
            <value/>
          </setting>
          <setting name="FIRMMOBILE" serializeAs="String">
            <value/>
          </setting>
          <setting name="FIRMEMAIL" serializeAs="String">
            <value/>
          </setting>
          <setting name="FIRMTIN" serializeAs="String">
            <value/>
          </setting>
          <setting name="FIRMPAN" serializeAs="String">
            <value/>
          </setting>
          <setting name="FIRMMANDITAXNO" serializeAs="String">
            <value/>
          </setting>
          <setting name="INITIALFONFIGDONE" serializeAs="String">
            <value>False</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="FIRMJURISDICTION" serializeAs="String">
            <value/>
          </setting>
          <setting name="FIRMBANKDETAILS" serializeAs="String">
            <value/>
          </setting>
          <setting name="FIRMDETAILS" serializeAs="String">
            <value/>
          </setting>
          <setting name="BILLFORMATNO" serializeAs="String">
            <value>0</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="PRINTERNAME" serializeAs="String">
            <value/>
          </setting>
        </Vegi_Manager.Properties.Settings>
      </userSettings>



      <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
      </startup>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Your sample is missing the opening "<configuration>" tag, but perhaps it just didn't copy over?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try putting the `configSections` as the first child element of `configuration`, because `configSections` should be the first element of configurations

So your config file will go like this:

```
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="Vegi_Manager.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConStr" connectionString="Integrated Security=false;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=funny;password=veryfunny;Initial Catalog=vegimanager;Data Source=.\sqlexpress;"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <userSettings>
    <Vegi_Manager.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="FIRMNAME" serializeAs="String">
        <value/>
      </setting>
      <setting name="FIRMADDRESS" serializeAs="String">
        <value/>
      </setting>
      <setting name="FIRMCITY" serializeAs="String">
        <value/>
      </setting>
      <setting name="FIRMSTATE" serializeAs="String">
        <value/>
      </setting>
      <setting name="FIRMPHONE" serializeAs="String">
        <value/>
      </setting>
      <setting name="FIRMMOBILE" serializeAs="String">
        <value/>
      </setting>
      <setting name="FIRMEMAIL" serializeAs="String">
        <value/>
      </setting>
      <setting name="FIRMTIN" serializeAs="String">
        <value/>
      </setting>
      <setting name="FIRMPAN" serializeAs="String">
        <value/>
      </setting>
      <setting name="FIRMMANDITAXNO" serializeAs="String">
        <value/>
      </setting>
      <setting name="INITIALFONFIGDONE" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="FIRMJURISDICTION" serializeAs="String">
        <value/>
      </setting>
      <setting name="FIRMBANKDETAILS" serializeAs="String">
        <value/>
      </setting>
      <setting name="FIRMDETAILS" serializeAs="String">
        <value/>
      </setting>
      <setting name="BILLFORMATNO" serializeAs="String">
        <value>0</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="PRINTERNAME" serializeAs="String">
        <value/>
      </setting>
    </Vegi_Manager.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Works like a hot knife through butter !

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late I know but when I remove this:

```
<startup>
   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
</startup>
```

then the error disappears.

Comment: You must have configSections as the first child "If the configSections element is in a configuration file, the configSections element must be the first child element of the configuration element.". If you move this config element down it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.
 Make sure that your app.config or web.config **starts with** the `<configSections>` tag inside the  `<configuration>` tab e.g

```
<configSections>
  <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="ConStr" connectionString="Integrated Security=false;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=funny;password=veryfunny;Initial Catalog=vegimanager;Data Source=.\sqlexpress;"/>
      </connectionStrings>
  <connectionStrings>
```

**after that make sure that the target Framework property of your project is not client profile**