# How to solve App config error Configuration system failed to initialize

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, exception, config

I came for advice.I'm trying to connect to the database through C#.But I have a problem with the App config file.It keeps throwing the App exception:,,

```
Configuration system failed to initialize
```

".I tried to add ,as advised here:[Configuration System Failed To Initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367203/configuration-system-failed-to-initialize) , but with no positive result.
So I wonder,if there is still a problem in the code,but I rather think that the problem is with the App config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    
    <add key="DataSource" value=" My Database'IP adress "/>
    <add key="Database" value="My database Name"/>
    <add key="Name" value="User name"/>
    <add key="Password" value="Password"/>
    
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're missing the `appSettings` element that wraps your key-value collection. It should look more like the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="DataSource" value=" My Database'IP adress "/>
    <add key="Database" value="My database Name"/>
    <add key="Name" value="User name"/>
    <add key="Password" value="Password"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```